# Python\GraphQL\HotChocolate Query Issue argument Decimal

Tags: python, graphql, hotchocolate

The query below works in GraphiQL Playground. When I put it into my Python script and execute the script I get below message:

> gql.transport.exceptions.TransportQueryError: {'message': 'Variable
> `idCustomer_chk` is required.', 'locations': [{'line': 1, 'column':
> 40}], 'extensions': {'code': 'HC0018', 'variable': 'idCustomer_chk'}}

This variable is declared and used in query. When I remove that argument and run the script it works. Seems to only fail with Decimal arguments. When I change it to Int! I get a message back stating expecting Type Decimal.

`'code': 'HC0018'` looks to come from HotChocolate, which states `"Variable xyz is required."`

Not sure what that message is referring to since that variable is in the query trying to be executed.

Any one have any ideas on what that message means and/or why when executing it is expecting a decimal and not an integer?  Column is defined as a NUMBER in database.

```
query check_it($tid_chk: String $sourceSys_chk: String $idCustomer_chk: Decimal!  ) 
    {VMI_DEV_Dhh 
                  {            Consumption(where: {tid: {eq: $tid_chk} sourceSys: {eq: $sourceSys_chk} idCustomer: {eq: $idCustomer_chk} } idSupplier: {eq: $idSupplier_chk} }  ) 
      {  items 
        { id }
      }
    }}
```

Comment: Column is defined as a NUMBER in database. - in what DB? You should specify that in your question.

Comment: Make sure you have idCustomer_chk defined all the way (in GraphQL/Python/DB). You might want to extract all unique values for that field to see what data type you actually need.

Comment: idCustomer_chk is a non-null decimal ... so you need to pass it in and it cannot be null.